# Replacing rsyslog with syslog-ng depends sylog-ng-core

Tags: 14.04, rsyslog

I am trying to replace the default `syslog` by `syslog-ng`.

`syslog-ng` is our standard and we want to use that `syslog` agent.

```
root@VirtualBox:~# apt-get install syslog-ng
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 syslog-ng : Depends: syslog-ng-core (>= 3.5.3)
             Depends: syslog-ng-mod-sql
             Depends: syslog-ng-mod-mongodb
             Depends: syslog-ng-mod-json
             Recommends: syslog-ng-mod-smtp
             Recommends: syslog-ng-mod-amqp
             Recommends: syslog-ng-mod-geoip
             Recommends: syslog-ng-mod-redis
             Recommends: syslog-ng-mod-stomp
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to install `syslog-ng-core` and `syslog-ng` at the same time:

```
sudo apt-get install syslog-ng-core syslog-ng
```

Comment: Hi Tung, this works like a charm ! Thanks a lot . Joeri

Comment: are there ubuntu specific guides?